# Iterating through a properties file in Ant

Tags: ant

So I need to write an Ant script that iterates through a properties file and uses the keys from that file to pull values from a few other properties files (using the same key).

I haven't been able to find any examples remotely similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. Is this something thats plausible with Ant? I know its rather old. I've never used Maven but I believe our platform would be able to support that if this isn't possible in Ant

Comment: But bear in mind that properties once set are immutable in ant. So pulling a value with the same name (=key) as a property already set will always return the same value.

Comment: .. what does 'pull values' mean ? You should provide more details.

Comment: @Rebse, I have 3 properties files, all of them have the same keys but different values. I need to iterate through one of them that contains true/false for values, and use the keys where the value is true to look up values in the other two properties files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<script>` command you can execute arbirary java/javascript code and do not supported code. 
For your case, perhaps some similar to :

```
<scriptdef name="iterateprops" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="src" />
    <![CDATA[
       importClass(java.util.Properties);
       importClass(java.io.FileInputStream);
       var src = attributes.get("src");
       var properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(new FileInputStream(src));
       var names = properties.propertyNames();
       while(names.hasMoreElements()) {
           println (names.nextElement());
       }

    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

An later use it:

```
<iterateprops src="file.properties" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the best way to do this!